# Best practice for changing the logo of a Liferay DXP/7 site

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-7

As there are several ways of changing a Liferay DXP/7 site's logo, I wanted to ask which one is the "best" way, conventional way.

The ways I currently have knowledge about are:

- Changing through Public Pages' Look and Feel options menu
- Changing through custom theme by:

  - Directly referring to its path in portal-normal header's `<img>` tag
  - Set a custom variable to contain it's path as text

Are there other, "better" ways or these summarize all? Out of all, which is the conventional way?

Comment: "Best practice" depends on what you want to achieve. Changing it through the UI is implemented - that would be a hint for this operation to be preferred. If you can't grant this level of access, you'd need to look for other solutions, so the answer is "it depends". IMHO this is not a good question for stackoverflow because it's not programming related and rather about an opinion than on hard facts.

Comment: What I want to achieve is stated in the question, which is changing the company logo.
I'm sorry, I'd consider my question programming related rather than opinion hunting, since I asked about the conventional way of  achieving my goal, and this could be done in several ways involving coding.

Comment: I would do it from public pages so the user can change it whenever he wants. If you do it using an img, css background or tomcat, you will have to do it with someone always with experience. It is my best advice from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on requirement.

In my opinion if you have logo in image form, you should upload here:

> Public/private Pages> configuration > Look & Feel > Logo

You should use custom field or look & feel custom field only if you have specific requirement. Otherwise it's best.

**FYI:** using logo from theme `portal-normal.ftl` is not a good idea, as it will not allow user to upload it's logo self. As liferay is a CMS, user should have right to do so.